# Show breakdates for R strucchange package

Tags: r, dataframe, data-structures, time-series, bayesian

Why does the following code not show the breakpoint dates for `strucchange` R package, by using the time series directly from my Excel data file?
Dummy Excel data at the bottom

```
library(strucchange)

df <- read_excel("breakpoint_test.xlsx")
tsrange <- read.zoo(df)
tsbreakpoint <- breakpoints(tsrange ~ 1)
summary(tsbreakpoint)

     Optimal (m+1)-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.formula(formula = tsrange ~ 1)

Breakpoints at observation number:
                     
m = 1       8        
m = 2       7 9      
m = 3       7 9 12   
m = 4     4 7 9 12   
m = 5   2 4 7 9 12   
m = 6   2 4 7 9 11 13

Corresponding to breakdates:
                                                                                   
m = 1                                       0.533333333333333                      
m = 2                                       0.466666666666667 0.6                  
m = 3                                       0.466666666666667 0.6 0.8              
m = 4                     0.266666666666667 0.466666666666667 0.6 0.8              
m = 5   0.133333333333333 0.266666666666667 0.466666666666667 0.6 0.8              
m = 6   0.133333333333333 0.266666666666667 0.466666666666667 0.6 0.733333333333333
                         
m = 1                    
m = 2                    
m = 3                    
m = 4                    
m = 5                    
m = 6   0.866666666666667

Fit:
                                                                  
m   0        1        2        3        4        5        6       
RSS 169758.9  26286.9  15077.7   4661.0   4599.3   4595.3   5012.0
BIC    188.0    165.4    162.5    150.3    155.5    160.9    167.7
```

Instead I have to manipulate my Excel data using `ts` in order for the breakpoint dates to appear in `summary`

```
tsrange2 <- ts(df$Value, start = c(2022,1), end = c(2023,3), frequency = 12)
tsbreakpoint2 <- breakpoints(tsrange2 ~ 1)
summary(tsbreakpoint2)

     Optimal (m+1)-segment partition: 

Call:
breakpoints.formula(formula = tsrange2 ~ 1)

Breakpoints at observation number:
                     
m = 1       8        
m = 2       7 9      
m = 3       7 9 12   
m = 4     4 7 9 12   
m = 5   2 4 7 9 12   
m = 6   2 4 7 9 11 13

Corresponding to breakdates:
                                                        
m = 1                   2022(8)                         
m = 2                   2022(7) 2022(9)                 
m = 3                   2022(7) 2022(9) 2022(12)        
m = 4           2022(4) 2022(7) 2022(9) 2022(12)        
m = 5   2022(2) 2022(4) 2022(7) 2022(9) 2022(12)        
m = 6   2022(2) 2022(4) 2022(7) 2022(9) 2022(11) 2023(1)

Fit:
                                                                  
m   0        1        2        3        4        5        6       
RSS 169758.9  26286.9  15077.7   4661.0   4599.3   4595.3   5012.0
BIC    188.0    165.4    162.5    150.3    155.5    160.9    167.7
```

Excel data:

| Dates | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 31-Jan-22 | 2 |
| 28-Feb-22 | 4 |
| 31-Mar-22 | 6 |
| 30-Apr-22 | 4 |
| 31-May-22 | 8 |
| 30-Jun-22 | 10 |
| 31-Jul-22 | 12 |
| 31-Aug-22 | 100 |
| 30-Sep-22 | 150 |
| 31-Oct-22 | 250 |
| 30-Nov-22 | 300 |
| 31-Dec-22 | 250 |
| 31-Jan-23 | 200 |
| 28-Feb-23 | 150 |
| 31-Mar-23 | 200 |